# Choose Database from Controller Constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

Doing something weird here. For sake of security, the project manager wants this ASP.Net MVC web app to use separate databases for each client. I already know that I'm going to be using the overload for the DataContext class that accepts a connection string as an argument to "hotswap" to another DB. The problem I'm facing is I *know* I don't want to write this logic in each and every action, to read in the first parameter of the URL (which in this case will be the client's name) and choose their database to build the DataContext against.

So .. How can I grab this data and somehow rig it up to create the DataContext is the Controller's Constructor using some value to connect to the right database?

I'm hoping this makes sense. More details -- Web App will run for multiple clients, and each client will have their own DataBase with Vendors, Items, Settings, etc... I'm really not sure what data is relevant here. :P Please forgive me!

**EDIT**: Why the downvotes? If I'm approaching something the wrong way ... can you give me a hint?

Comment: Why is a project manager dictating implementation?

Comment: the PM is also a developer and is voicing his best concept of security, for preventing data from bleeding from one client to another.. Or unauthorized access, of course. :P

Comment: That's a mistake. The amount of development overhead, because of this, is going to be significant. And there can still be security mistakes here. Someone should push back against this idea.

Comment: @BobHorn So, instead of using separate databases, you would instead insist that we should just use one? I would assume that there would then be a 'Client' field that would identify which rows belong to which client, and said field would be included in the DB Schema. Does that sound like a better approach?

Comment: Some people don't live/work in the real world apparently.  Manager/project managers/business owners/clients often dictate implementation.  That is a fact of life.

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't mean those decisions should be blindly followed. Pushing the configuration up to the level where the code has to choose the database just complicates things. Just like you could choose the wrong row in a DB, you could also connect to the wrong DB.

Comment: @The1nk Yes, that sounds like a better approach.

Comment: Btw, maintaining a DB per client doesn't scale well. What happens if you get 200 clients? 2000? Are you going to maintain that many databases? And what problem is solved by choosing the DB in code? That can still have bugs in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I'm going to push back and explain this is a huge issue for scalability, and instead will use a `Client` column to differentiate different datasets.

Thanks for all your input!